# Do D3D11/D2D1 Device&DeviceContexts need to be reloaded on D2DERR_RECREATE_TARGET?

Tags: directx, direct3d, direct2d, direct3d11

[learn.microsoft.com](https://stackoverflow.com) is pretty light on specific details...

I started learning Direct2D using `ID2D1RenderTarget` but then realized I should be using device contexts and the swap chain. I would have to imagine all of the following are device dependent and should need to be released and recreated on `D2DERR_RECREATE_TARGET` :

```
ID3D11Device* mD3DDevice;
ID3D11DeviceContext* mD3DDeviceContext;
IDXGIDevice1* mDXGIDevice;
ID2D1Device* mD2DDevice;
ID2D1DeviceContext* mD2DDeviceContext;
```

Of course the swap chain/target bitmap would need to be recreated but I haven't found anything that explicitly says one way or the other about devices/device contexts... When I look at sample code I sometimes see them being recreated and sometimes I don't...

Any clarification would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks.

I tried Googling, looking at forum posts, sample code. I don't know how to force a `D2DERR_RECREATE_TARGET` to be flagged and then check if they've been invalidated.

Comment: I think it's basically an equivalent of "device lost" condition. So you'll need to recreate anything that's using d3d objects internally, and d3d objects that you created yourself on that device, and finally device itself.

Comment: Render Targets and device contexts are the same. In fact ID2D1DeviceContext inherits from ID2D1RenderTarget. So you need to release all device contexts and render targets and objects created from them (bitmap, brushes), but not necessarily D3D device nor DXGI devices.